# Issue Extracting Tokens in Spring Security 4.2.7 with Spring Authorization Server (Spring Security 6) and OIDC Flow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have a dedicated Spring Authorization Server (Spring Security 6) where I've configured the OIDC flow with PKCE for authentication. I have two applications, one running Spring Security 5.7.5 and the other running Spring Boot 1.4 with Spring Security 4.2.7.

In the first application (Spring Security 5.7.5), everything works as expected. It accepts the token and extracts it successfully. However, in the second application (Spring Boot 1.4 with Spring Security 4.2.7), I'm encountering issues while extracting the token and during configuration.

Are there any known compatibility issues or configuration considerations when integrating a Spring Authorization Server with OIDC flow (Spring Security 6) into older versions of Spring Security like 4.2.7?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 4.2 is not supported. Please see [the support timeline](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#support). The answer to your question is not known and likely won't be known because it is **strongly not recommended** to use an old version. Please consider upgrading to a supported version, which has the benefit of being known to work.